# how i can swipe from x.html to y.html?

Tags: javascript, html, swipe

i wanna make a swipe from site to site but how ?

my code :

```
enter code here 
function processingRoutine() {
var swipedElement = document.getElementById(triggerElementID);
if ( swipeDirection == 'left' ) {
    // REPLACE WITH YOUR ROUTINES
    //swipedElement.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
    event.preventDefault();
} else if ( swipeDirection == 'right' ) {
    // REPLACE WITH YOUR ROUTINES
    //swipedElement.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    event.preventDefault();
} else if ( swipeDirection == 'up' ) {
    // REPLACE WITH YOUR ROUTINES
    //swipedElement.style.backgroundColor = 'maroon';
} else if ( swipeDirection == 'down' ) {
    // REPLACE WITH YOUR ROUTINES
    //swipedElement.style.backgroundColor = 'purple';
}
```

and html code

```
enter code here
<?php
include ("y.html");
?>
</div>
<div class="swipe-item" data-part="1">Ich bin Seite Y</div>
<button onclick="jQuery('#swiper').trigger('left')">Swipe Up</button>    
<button onclick="jQuery('#swiper').trigger('right')">Swipe Down</button>
```

i wanna looks like this :

x-html (swipe) to y.html

and

y-html (swipe) to x.html

back and forward, i need help

Comment: Do you want to show next page on swipe event ? or you need to move the page 1 along with showing the page 2 during swiping ?

Comment: i wanna show next page on swipe event